# HashMap: Use Object as Key and use the methods of that key

Tags: java, hashmap

My HashMap currently looks like this:

```
HashMap<MyObject, Integer> hash = new HashMap<MyObject, Integer>();
```

Is there anyway to access the key objects, given the `hash` object and thus to use the methods of the Key-Objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HashMap<MyObject, Integer> hash = new HashMap<MyObject, Integer>();
for(Map.Entry<MyObject,Integer> entry:hash.entrySet()){
 entry.getKey().yourMethod(); //access method in key
}
```

This way you can access method in key. `entry.getKey()` return an `MyObject` which is your key. Now you can access the method in key.

Answer (score 2):

`Object` is a poor choice as key type. Use any class that

- Is immutable
- Implements proper `equals` and `hashCode` methods (important!)

`String` and `Integer` are ready-made candidtates, but you may as well implement your own key class, so you should then have `Map<UbuKey, Integer>` and may use all methods of that key class.

Comment: I'm sorry with object i didnt mean the class Object i meant any class. It's actually my own class called 'Flight'

Comment: @Ubuntix Write your question properly from next time that will give you appropriate answers

Comment: Yes sorry. I fixed it. :)

Comment: “`Object` is a poor choice as key type.” I disagree with that claim. Given direct instances of class `Object` (not subclasses) they fulfill the contract perfectly: they are immutable (they don’t have any state) and they have proper `equals` and `hashCode` implementations (using the object identity).

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you get map key you can use methods on that key. My suggestion is to assign implementation to interface not to implementation :)

```
Map<Object, Integer> hash = new HashMap<Object, Integer>();
        hash.keySet().iterator().next().yourMethod();
```

But remember to check if there is any object in your iterator and you get not null to invoke yourMethod on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can but if the methods are from your own object rather than object you'll need to change your map to this:

```
HashMap<MyObject, Integer> hash = new HashMap<MyObject, Integer>();
for(Map.Entry<MyObject, Integer> entry : hash.entrySet()) {
    entry.getKey().myMethod();
}
```

Or cast the Object to MyObject:

```
HashMap<Object, Integer> hash = new HashMap<Object, Integer>();
for(Map.Entry<Object, Integer> entry : hash.entrySet()) {
    ((MyObject entry.getKey()).myMethod();
}
```

However I'm not sure HashMap is the best choice of collection for what you're trying to do. as @Gyro Gearless says Object is not normally a good choice of key for a HashMap.

Comment: I meant my personal Class. I'm sorry. I fixed my post to MyObject